# Remove %20 in the display text when inserting links in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

We have a requirement that when the user inserts a hyperlink in Excel, the %20 in the URL will be replaced by either - or _ so that it is readable in the excel file. Is this possible via macro or other options? We just want the display text of the hyperlink to be readable and without %20 (but of course the actual URL with the %20 remains unchanged). 
Kindly advise as I'm totally new to macro and programming.

Comment: Technically `%20` is an HTML-encoded whitespace (ASCII 32 in hexadecimal => 20); you'll want to be able to handle anything that can come up in a URL though - a friend wrote [this helper code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/145170/23788) that can do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

More as a (hopefully helpful) pointer in the right direction - as [@Matthieu Guindon points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51958840/remove-20-in-the-display-text-when-inserting-links-in-excel#comment90868455_51958840), you'll probably want to handle more than just the HTML-encoded whitespace - you can capture the hyperlink insertion with the [Workbook.SheetChange event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbook.SheetChange), and then modify the `TextToDisplay` of a hyperlink.

For the specific case of `%20`, that might look something like this (inserted in the `ThisWorkbook` module):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim hlink As Hyperlink

    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each hlink In Target.Hyperlinks
        hlink.TextToDisplay = Replace(hlink.TextToDisplay, "%20", "_")
    Next hlink

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a few hyperlinks, it can be done by hand quite easily:
Just right-click the hyperlink and select `Edit Hyperlink...`. Here you can change the `Text to display` to whatever you want. The real address remains unchanged.